# UITableView Deleting rows in iOS 11

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode9

When I trying to deleting rows, at first it behaves pretty good. However, at the instance that `content size` firstly smaller than the `border` of the tableview, when deleting rows the whole table suddenly jumps 1 row up...

Here is my delete row action,

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        Results.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

In `ViewDidload` I've already implement the code below

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0;
self.tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 0;
self.tableView.estimatedSectionFooterHeight = 0;
```

The animation just when wrong only when the content's height first become smaller to the border... After that the animation also ran properly...

and here's the [GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCZgQ.gif) shows what happening...
is that a bug in iOS 11?

Comment: Have you tried doing that on a real device?

Comment: Oh nope but I found many peoples uses other versions of Xcodes and simulators seems did not have similar problem... So I am wondering is that a problem that occurs on certain version... But I find the problem could be solved by my answer below...So maybe nobody asked is just because it's too simple to solve but for greenhand like me it's a disaster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK finally I got an solution, and it looks good. I add the code below to the delete action:

```
if(tableView.contentSize.height<=tableView.bounds.height+100.0 && tableView.contentSize.height>tableView.bounds.height) {
    tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
}
// The 100.0f is the cell height.
```

The 100.0f is the cell's height. So when the content's height firstly smaller than the tableView's border, the tableview scrolls to the very top, and the glitch animation is covered by the scrolling animation.